# Onclick of checkbox how to change button color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

How can i change color of button during onclick
After user enter all fields and click on checkbox, button color should change.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
       maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
       return !this.terms || (this.fullname.length  < this.max) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
   || (this.area.length < this.maxarea) || (this.city.length < this.maxcity);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.register-button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/ :maxlength="maxmobile"> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
  <button  class="register-button" :disabled='isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

How can i change color of button during onclick
After user enter all fields and click on checkbox, button color should change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class binding functionality of Vue.
`:class="{'selected': isDisabled}"`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      terms: false,
      fullname:'',
       maxfullname: 10,
      mobile: '',
      maxmobile: 10,
      area: '',
      maxarea: 12,
      city: '',
      maxcity: 12,
      gstin: '',
      maxgstin: 12,
      email: '',
      maxemail: 15
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled: function(){
        return this.terms && this.fullname.length < this.max && this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile && this.gstin.length < this.maxgstin && this.email.length < this.maxemail;
    }
  }
 })
```

```css
.register-button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee1d24;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.selected {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='terms' type='checkbox' v-model='terms'/> I accept terms!!!
      <input id="fullname" type='text' v-model='fullname'  :maxlength="maxfullname"/> name
      <input id="mobile" type='text' v-model='mobile'/ :maxlength="maxmobile"> mobile
       <input id="area" type='text' v-model='area' :maxlength="maxarea"/> area
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city':maxlength="maxcity"/> city
    </label>
    
  </p>
  <button class="register-button" :class="{'selected': isDisabled}" :disabled='!isDisabled'>Send Form</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine, but for the below computed how to give above condition

Comment: computed: {
   isDisabled: function(){
      return !this.terms || (this.fullname.length  < this.max) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
       || (this.gstin.length < this.maxgstin) || (this.email.length < this.maxemail);
    }
  },

Comment: Just replace `this.fullname` with `(this.fullname.length < this.max)` and others as well respectively

Comment: with length property condition is not satisfying with the code above in comments

Comment: Tried placing like  return !this.terms || (this.fullname.length   < this.max) || (this.mobile.length < this.maxmobile)
       || (this.gstin.length < this.maxgstin) || (this.email.length < this.maxemail);

Comment: Tried its not working some conditions because from computed property some conditions failing.

Comment: Can you please update according to the above computed property with all conditions

Comment: I have update as per your computed property provided in comments.

Comment: Tried that it's not working,  having some issue near computed property. Because of the max length and length  for each field and not condition. Those are missing in your updated code.

Comment: Can you please update your code in the question?